# Pydantic strict mode - cast away Optional

Tags: python, strict, pydantic

I have a model like below

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class FooModel(BaseModel):
    bar: Optional[int]
    baz: Optional[str]
```

Is it possible to dynamically get rid of Optional/make `bar` and `baz` fields required? Effectively to dynamically convert `FooModel` above to

```
class FooModel(BaseModel):
    bar: int
    baz: str
```

I've tried

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class FooModel(BaseModel):
    bar: Optional[int]
    baz: Optional[str]

    def __init__(self, strict: bool = False, **data) -> None:
        if strict:
            for name in self.__fields__.keys():
                self.__fields__[name].required = True
        super().__init__(**data)
```

but this affects all other classes which inherit from `FooModel` (`__fields__` is a class variable and I didn't manage to deep copy it), which of course is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Why classes that inherit from `FooModel` shouldn't have these attributes required?

If, for some reason, only `FooModel` needs to have `foo` and `bar` required, you can add a check in your `if`.

```py
    def __init__(self, strict: bool = False, **data) -> None:
        if strict and type(self) == FooModel:
```

However, you can also check [Required Optional fields](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#required-optional-fields); this field is required when the model object is created, but its value can also be `None`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class FooModel(BaseModel):
    bar: Optional[int] = ...
    baz: Optional[str] = ...

class BarModel(FooModel): pass

FooModel(bar=42, baz="hello world")
BarModel(bar=None, baz=None)
```

Comment: I want those fields to be required and not None at the same time. The problem is I am unable to to a deep copy of `self.__fields__` (as that is a class attribute) for some reason.